# WPF change Image when mouse hover on button

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I'm trying to change the image when mouse is over a button, but it's not working here is what am trying to do :

```
<Button x:Name="Play" Content="" ClickMode="Press" BorderThickness="0" UseLayoutRounding="True" Height="120" Width="224">
    <Button.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Resources/Play 1.gif"/>
    </Button.Background>
    <Button.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="ImageBrush.ImageSource" Value="Resources/Play 2.gif"></Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Button.Triggers>
</Button>
```

But this gives me this error :  `Triggers collection members must be of type EventTrigger.`

How would I make it work?

Comment: Possible duplicate [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17657048/how-to-make-a-image-button-that-change-the-image-when-mouse-over-button-wpf/17657321#17657321)

Comment: Or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789961/trying-to-add-a-trigger-to-a-button-to-change-the-buttons-content-property

Comment: FrameworkElement.Triggers only accepts event trigger. You might need overwrite Button's ControlTemplate and define your triggers in ControlTemplate.Triggers. As dowhilefor and Chris suggest, there are many same or similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

It's correct - you can only put EventTriggers in there. You need to move your Trigger into the button's Style:

```
<Button x:Name="Play" Content="" ClickMode="Press" BorderThickness="0" UseLayoutRounding="True" Height="120" Width="224">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="..\Resources\Play 1.gif"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="..\Resources\Play 2.gif"/>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
         </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Something like that, I think (haven't tested it).

EDIT: This switches between the correct images, but it doesn't work correctly (it starts off with Play 1.gif, transitions to Play 2.gif, but then transitions to the button's underlying colour). I think you'll have to override the button's `ControlTemplate` to prevent this from happening, as suggested in the comments.

Comment: ummm the image of the back-ground disappeared and it's not working!

Comment: I edited my answer after testing to make it slightly better, but it doesn't work correctly. Sorry. Still, it eliminates one possibility.

Comment: The problem here is that the default `Button` template for some Windows themes basically ignores `Background` on mouse over. It changes the button colour on mouse over with an extra element in the visual tree (typically a `Border` or `Rectangle`) on top of the background. The problem is unrelated to triggers - the background gets obscured even if you just set the background to be a fixed bitmap that you don't attempt to change. (Even setting a plain colour as the background has the same problem.) Chris, your suggestion - change the control template - is the only option.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Window x:Class="Image_ChangeOnHover"
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
 Title="Image_ChangeOnHover" Height="300" Width="300">
 <Grid>
   <Image Stretch="None" Margin="10">
     <Image.Resources>
       <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
         <!-- Default image -->
         <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Resources/Off2.png"/>
       <Style.Triggers>
         <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
           <!-- Hover image -->
           <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Resources/On.png"/>
         </Trigger>
       </Style.Triggers>
     </Style>
    </Image.Resources>
   </Image>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```